# I don't want a file being committed to svn server. What should I do?

Tags: svn

I have checked out a a directory named with `src`.
I modified some files in the directory and I need to commit the changes which I have made.
But I do not want to update for example `app.js` in `src\app` folder.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It depends. Do you want to prevent everyone from committing it? Just yourself? Or maybe just omit from current commit and possibly commit it some time later?

Comment: Just for myself and maybe commit it much later.

Comment: In such case you may want to `svn add` it and then `svn changelist` it.